# Как найти дату по формату дд.мм?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, aiogram, google-spreadsheet

Никак не могу понять почему не удается сделать поиск по дате в гугл таблице. Например, в телеграмм боте отправляю сообщение "Дата 222", он присылается данные которые есть в этом столбце(скрин прикрепил). А если отправить "Дата 21.09" он не может увидеть эту дату и соответственно не видит данные с этого столбца. И так со всеми числами, где есть разделение с точкой. Т.е. если целые числа(пример 222), то он видит этот столбец, а если раздельные(пример дд.мм), то не видит. Также пробовал и 21.09.23 и 21.09.2023, всё равно не находит. В гугл таблице в одной из ячеек пробовал убрать формулу дд.мм.гг., всё равно никак не находит. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```py
@dp.message_handler(filters.Regexp(regexp=r"(((Д|а)та)(\s)([-+]?\b[\d+.,]+\b))"))
async def raspisanie_handler(message_from: types.Message) -> None:
   user_id: str = str(message_from.from_id)
   command, number = get_command_number(message_from.md_text)

   values = bot._google_table.search_raspisanie(number)
   if values == -1:
      message = 'Такой даты не существует, либо его нет в расписании '
```

Но догадываюсь, что вероятнее всего не верные регулярные выражения

```
[-+]?\b[\d+.,]+\b
```

[image: Скрин с 21.09]
[image: Ответ на 222]
[image: Скрин с 222]

Comment: Разобрался самостоятельно.

Comment: Если вопрос более неактуален, вы можете оформить на него исчерпывающий ответ, либо удалить.

Comment: Разобрался, а ответ не выложил. Мой первый комментарий актуален.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При отправке сообщения, ставился слэш перед точкой. Убрал его с помощью реплейса.

```
number = number.replace('\\', '')
```